# How to get the ids of div looping through foreach in jquery variable

Tags: php, jquery

Hello there i'm having trouble in getting the id's of a div that is stored in an foreach loop. What i want to do is to get the id one by one in jquery as the ids are looping in the php code.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".cat-anchor").click(function(){
            var target=('get the id of cat-title class here')
        });
    });
</script>
<?php
foreach($cat_arr['cat_pro'] as $cat_name){
echo "<div class='cat-back'>";
echo "<a href='#".$cat_name[0]."' class='cat-anchor'>".$cat_name[1]."</a> <br>";
echo "</div>";
}

    foreach($cat_arr['cat_pro'] as $mykey=>$myvalues){
        echo '<div name="'.$myvalues[1].'" class="cat-title" id="'.$myvalues[0].'">
        <h2>'.$myvalues[1].'</h2></div>';
?>
```

Comment: What's the problem with your code? Does it throw an error? Does it return incorrect results?

Comment: where is `cat-anchor`

Comment: no its not returning errors it just not doing anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".cat-anchor").click(function(){
            $(".cat-title").each(function(index, element) {
                var target=$(this).attr("id");
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Trying this, you'll get object for each `div` and use them as as you wish.

Answer (score 0):

```js
<div class="cat-title" id="1"></div>
<div class="cat-title" id="2"></div>
<div class="cat-title" id="3"></div>
<div class="cat-title" id="4"></div>
<input type="button" class="cat-anchor" value="get ids">

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".cat-anchor").click(function(){
          var target='';
          var divs = $(".cat-title");
          for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
            target += divs[i].id;
          };
          alert(target);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".cat-anchor").click(function(){
            var target = $(this).attr('id');
        });
    });
</script>
```

Just Google for how to retrieve an element's attribute from jQuery. The [.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) function will help.

Answer (score 0):

First define a variable which increments till the loop completion and also append the same variable at  `id="your-div-name'.$i.'"` as shown below

```
$i=1

foreach($cat_arr['cat_pro'] as $mykey=>$myvalues){
    echo '<div name="'.$myvalues[1].'" class="cat-title'.$i.'" id="'.$myvalues[0].'">
    <h2>'.$myvalues[1].'</h2></div>';
    $i++;
}
```

and then when writing your script just execute the loop as no.of times prev loop executes, simultaneously echo the number for div as here. Hope this is clear!

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(".cat-anchor").click(function(){
 <?php
   for($j=0;$j<=$i;$j++){
           echo 'var target=document.getElementById("cat-title'.$j.'").innerHTML;'; 
 }
  ?>

    });
});
</script>
```